# How to get rid of "Ambiguous type variable `msg0' in the constraints"

Tags: haskell, protocol-buffers

I have a problem with protocol-buffers in Haskell.  I'm writing a simple UDP receiver and get the error:

```
src/Main.hs:39:25:
    Ambiguous type variable `msg0' in the constraints:
      (Wire msg0)
        arising from a use of `messageGet' at src/Main.hs:39:25-34
      (Text.ProtocolBuffers.Reflections.ReflectDescriptor msg0)
        arising from a use of `messageGet' at src/Main.hs:39:25-34
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: (messageGet (B.pack mesg))
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `case (messageGet (B.pack mesg)) of {
         Left person -> putStrLn $ show person
         Right err -> error $ "Failed to parse address book." }'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      return
      $ case (messageGet (B.pack mesg)) of {
          Left person -> putStrLn $ show person
          Right err -> error $ "Failed to parse address book." }
```

How can I follow it's advice?  (I'm just learning Haskell.)

My Code follows:

```
module Main where

import Data.Bits
import Network.Socket -- hiding (send, sendTo, recv, recvFrom)
-- import Network.Socket.ByteString
import Network.BSD
import Data.List
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
import Text.ProtocolBuffers.Header (defaultValue, uFromString)
import Text.ProtocolBuffers.WireMessage (messageGet, messagePut, Wire)

import Data.Sequence ((><), fromList)

import AddressBookProtos.AddressBook
import AddressBookProtos.Person
import AddressBookProtos.Person.PhoneNumber
import AddressBookProtos.Person.PhoneType

import Network.Socket
import System.Posix.Directory
import System.Posix.Files
import System.Posix.IO
import System.Posix.Process
import System.Exit


echoserver :: IO ()
echoserver = do
           withSocketsDo $ do
                   sock <- socket AF_INET Datagram 0
                   bindSocket sock (SockAddrInet 4567 iNADDR_ANY)
                   socketRx sock

socketRx :: Socket -> IO ()
socketRx sock = do

         (mesg, recv_count, client) <- recvFrom sock 1500

         return $ case (messageGet (B.pack mesg)) of
                       Left person -> putStrLn $ show person
                       Right err   -> error $ "Failed to parse address book."
         socketRx sock



main::IO()
main = echoserver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation at http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/protocol-buffers/2.0.9/doc/html/Text-ProtocolBuffers-WireMessage.html#v:messageGet, the type signature of `messageGet` is

```
messageGet :: (ReflectDescriptor msg, Wire msg) => ByteString -> Either String (msg, ByteString)
```

The return value is either a `String` error message or a `msg` and a residual `ByteString`.  In your code, you have written

```
case messageGet (B.pack mesg) of
  Left person -> putStrLn $ show person
  Right err   -> error "Failed to parse address book."
```

If it returns a `(msg, ByteString)`, that value is bound to the variable `err`.  Since `err` is ignored, the actual type of `msg` is not determined, which is what the error message is telling you.  In fact, *any* type that's an instance of `Wire` and `ReflectDescriptor` will work, but the program will behave differently for each type!  Since the compiler doesn't know what type you want, you have to specify it.  You can specify it by annotating the return type of `messageGet`.

```
case messageGet (B.pack mesg) :: Either String (X, ByteString) of -- Use the actual message type in place of 'X'
  Left person -> putStrLn $ show person
  Right err   -> error "Failed to parse address book."
```

You probably also meant to switch the `Left` and `Right` cases in your code.  `Right` is the non-error case (think "wrong" and "right").  Switching the cases will not get rid of the error message on its own.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having trouble working out what X should be.  I've tried 'Wire' (Expecting one more argument to Wire) and 'Wire Person' (Predicate Wire Person used as a type).

Answer (score 1):

Add a type annotation like this:

```
return $ case messageGet (B.pack mesg) :: Either Something SomethingElse of
```

(I'm not familiar with protocol-buffers, so I don't know what types `Something` and `SomethingElse` should be --- replace them with the actual types you require.)